# Bootstrap 4: between col-lg and col-md sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So i am creating a tribute page in which you can view here --> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/xpEqWX

This is all based on the jumbotron in which you can find on lines 2 & 3 of the code.

---

This is `col-lg-8` with `offset-lg-2` to center it, `1920px` width:

[image]

---

This is also `col-lg-8` in effect, with a width of `993px`:

[image]

---

Then it finally switches over to `col-md-12` at around `990px`. This now makes it so the jumbotron takes up all 12 columns giving the text more space:

[image]

---

As you can see, there is lots of range for the `lg`. It has the same affect at `1000px` as `1920px`. This can make it annoying as my `lg` setting looks good at 1920px, but by around `1000px` it still hasn't switched over to md, causing the images to be awkwardly small. This is around a 1000px difference and is messing me up. Is there anyway i can go in between lg and md, and so with any other size? Is it a class like `col-lg-` that i can use to maybe add 10 columns and 1 offset at the halfway point between lg and md? Would i have to check using `@media` (css) to then change the columns that way if possible?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

could you use?

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

Comment: To fine tune the breakpoints further write custom `@media` queries or change the default `$grid-breakpoints` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid 
I'm not sure if it's possible to do the former inside codepen

Comment: Yeah i'm a little confused on it... The ```xl``` still takes up ```600px``` causing most of the same affect.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
```